# Figma дизайн перенести в pyqt код

Tags: python, pyqt, figma

Я сделал красивый дизайн в figma, но столкнулся с проблемой что плохо знаю pyqt. может кто-то знает как из дизайна сделать pyqt код. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtdesignstudio/figmaqtbridge.html

Comment: спасибо большое!